# GruntJS setup: No targets found

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

### The code

My latest commit is in [a repo on GitHub](https://github.com/trevordmiller/trevordmiller-core).

### The problem...

I am setting up a project (link above) using GruntJS. While trying to run any Grunt task, I'm getting a `No "<insert-taskname>" targets found`; a few examples:

1. > > No "browserSync" targets found.
   > >     Warning: Task "browserSync" failed. Use --force to continue.
2. > > No "jshint" targets found.
   > >     Warning: Task "jshint" failed. Use --force to continue.
3. > > No "sass" targets found.
   > >     Warning: Task "sass" failed. Use --force to continue.

### What I'm doing

I am using external `.js` Grunt config files using the [load-grunt-configs](https://github.com/creynders/load-grunt-configs) plugin. I have used a very similar setup in other projects without problems. I'm passing the shared Grunt variables which were initialized in the `Gruntfile.js` to each of the `grunt-configs` files using the `options` object that is a part of the `load-grunt-configs` plugin.

### What I've tried so far...

I've tried checking my Grunt variables that are being used in the external config files, double checking my syntax and bracket matching, and searching through other stack overflow questions with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using the idiomatic and built-in methods of breaking up your Gruntfile instead. 3rd party solutions tend to stray far from the Grunt APIs.

Create a folder named `tasks/` and within that folder add files similar to what you're currently doing now.

Load all of those files in your main Gruntfile using `grunt.loadTasks()`:

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Initialize config.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: require('./package.json'),
  });

  // Load per-task config from separate files.
  grunt.loadTasks('tasks');
};
```

Each of those files are formatted like mini Gruntfiles. Here is an example for jshint:

```
// tasks/jshint.js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.config('jshint', {
    app: {
      options: {jshintrc: 'app/.jshintrc'},
      src: ['app/**/*.js'],
    },
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
};
```

Here is a full example of this solution from the creator of Grunt himself: https://github.com/cowboy/wesbos

Comment: This solved my module loading problem - thank you! But, how can I share variables across the external `.js` files now? I tried creating a global object and adding properties to it and then placing this in my EJS paths like `<%= gruntScope.srcJsFiles %>` but this doesn't work; if I need to hard code the paths into each config file then I will, but I would prefer to keep everything DRY and would imagine there is a way to do so...?

Comment: I have updated the example repo on GitHub; see the `Gruntfile.js` and files in the `grunt-configs` folder for reference:
https://github.com/trevordmiller/trevordmiller-core

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to find a solution to the problem (of sharing variables across seperate config files) on http://chrisawren.com/posts/Advanced-Grunt-tooling under the "Using Variables in your configuration" section. For those reading, you need to create a global object and add properties to it as I was trying to do before, but then you need to pass it to a property inside of `grunt.initConfig` which you can access from other files.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is inside your config tasks.

you are doing

```
module.exports = {
```

you need to do:

```
module.exports.tasks = {
```

other than that i recommend following kyle's answer, as it is much cleaner to use grunt's built in features!